# can i reduce my code using loop for varaible or array

Tags: javascript, arrays

now the repeating code problem has been solved but when executed the if condition function of **moveHorse** is being executed repeteadly. please help.
    function moveHorse(horseId)

);
        interval=setInterval(function(){moveHorse('horseID');},20);

```
   }
```

now the repeating code problem has been solved but when executed the if condition function of **moveHorse** is being executed repeteadly. please help.

Comment: Just pass the horse into the function instead of writing `var horse4 = document.getElementById('horse4');` all over the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in the element ID as the function parameter, then you can refactor the code to -

```
// TODO: rename your local variable name because now it doesn't need to be horse4, right?
function horseUp(horseElementId) {
  var horse = document.getElementById(horseElementId);
  // do the rest
}

function horseDown(horseElementId) {
  var horse = document.getElementById(horseElementId);
  // do the rest
}

function horseleft(horseElementId) {
  var horse = document.getElementById(horseElementId);
  // do the rest
}
```

To use the function, pass in the element Id

```
horseUp('horse4');
horseLeft('horse2');
```

and so on

Comment: the previous problem was solved but now i have given the value of horseID as horse1 at interval function. but the value of horseID  passes till horseDown in the moveHorse function but not in the IF condition of horseDown function. and the repeating execution of moveHorse function was due to same function name as variable. PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Since the only part that appears to be different is the horse being changed, just pass that in. For example:

```
var horse4 = document.getElementById('horse4');

function horseUp(horse, moving) {

    var horseTop = horse.offsetTop;
    var random = Math.random() * 2.7 + 2;

    horse.style.top = horseTop - 0.5 * random + 'px';

    if (horseTop <= window.innerHeight * 0.05) {
        clearInterval(interval4);
        interval4 = setInterval(moving, 10);
    }
}
```

There's a few other variables like `interval4` that you'll need to figure out, but this should give you the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

May use OOP:

```
function Horse(id) {
   this.el = document.getElementById(id);
}

Horse.prototype={
  move(x,y){
    this.el.offsetTop+=(this.y=typeof y !=="undefined"?y:this.y);
    this.el.offsetLeft+=(this.x=typeof x !== "undefined"?x:this.x);
  },
  up(){
    this.move(0,0.5*Math.random() * 2.7 + 2* + 'px';
  },
  down(){ this.move(0,- 0.5* Math.random() * 2.4 + 2);}, 
  left(){ this.move(0.5* Math.random() * 2.4 + 2,0);}, 
  right(){ this.move(- 0.5* Math.random() * 2.4 + 2,0);},
  setInterval(){
    this.interval=setInterval(_=>this.move(),10);
  }
}
```

use like this:

```
var horse4=new Horse("horse4");
horse4.setInterval();
horse4.left();
```